# innerHtml.replace replaces tags and not just text

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, innerhtml

I currently try to replace certain words from an utterance with a `<span>WORD</span` element. I get the start and end indices from the words from the backend. An utterance can have several words which will be replaced. So I just iterate over the array of words to replaced and try to replace the words in the utterance.

However, I tried doing it with `innerHtml.replace(word, <span>word</span>)`. The problem here is, that when for example the second word is 'sp' the sp of the tag of the first word is replaced instead of the word 'sp' in my utterance.

I then tried to replace the word my putting in the start and end index of the word (which I thought would solve the problem). But it seems like if the start and end index points on 'sp' it still replaces the part of span and not the word I wanted to replace.

So, I am looking for a way to replace only words in an utterance and not the HTML elements with the `<span>WORD</span>`.

My Code right now:

```
var label = document.getElementById('match-text' + index);
      label.innerHTML = label.innerHTML.replace(label.innerText.substring(entity.start, entity.end),'<span ng-click="showEntityDetailsPage($event, ' + index + ', ' + entityIndex + ')" style="background-color:'
      + color + '; border: 3px solid ' + borderColor + ';" class="highlighted-entities">' + label.innerText.substring(entity.start, entity.end) + '</span>');
      $compile(label)($scope);
```

Comment: You could iterate through all the child nodes found in `label` and do the replace on their innerText properties.  Using innerHTML won't work for the reason you discovered.

Comment: @James so at the beginning, my label only has one child node which is the whole utterance. So, I guess that would not work then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further to my comment, here is how I would implement that.  In this example the anchor tag's html attribute contains "oo" and so does the tfoot tag, and they do not get changed.

```js
function replaceText(obj, search, wrapElement, elementClass) {
  switch (obj.nodeType) {
    case 3: // it's a text node
      if (obj.nodeValue.indexOf(search) > -1) {
        var bits = obj.nodeValue.split(search);
        var nextSib = obj.nextSibling;
        obj.nodeValue = bits[0];
        for (var i=1; i < bits.length; i++) {
          var el = document.createElement(wrapElement);
          el.className = elementClass;
          el.innerHTML = search;
          var tn = document.createTextNode(bits[i]);
          if (nextSib) {
            obj.parentNode.insertBefore(tn, nextSib);
            obj.parentNode.insertBefore(el, tn);
          } else {
            obj.parentNode.appendChild(tn);
            obj.parentNode.insertBefore(el, tn);
          }
        }
        return 2*(bits.length-1);
      }
    break;
    default: // it's not a text node
      for (var i=0; i < obj.childNodes.length; i++) {
        var j = replaceText(obj.childNodes[i], search, wrapElement, elementClass);
        if (j) i+=j;
      }
    break;
  }
}

replaceText(document.getElementById('starthere'), "oo", "span", "myspanclass");
```

```css
.myspanclass {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id='starthere'>Noonhour
  <span>Boondoggle
    <a href="http://google.com">Google</a>
  </span>
  The Moon is a Balloon
  <table><tfoot><tr><th>oops!</th></tr></tfoot></table>
</div>
```

Comment: that does not work for me as nodeValue only takes text, but my 'replace' is always a html content (like <span>word</span>).

Comment: OK I didn't read your question properly (which might explain the DV).  Anyway give this a try, instead of a search regex and a replace text it now takes a search string, an element name to wrap around it, and a classname that the element will use.  It's tricky because you have to create new elements a lot, as you can't put html into text nodes.